# Saving data from a CRUD (grails) in a xlsx file

Tags: grails

I am creating a CRUD application with grails and I would save some  data in a xlsx file. For example, when a new user create a new profile using the UI, How can I save these data in a xlsx file in the same time? Putting each field in a specific colunm.

Answer (score 0):

One way to save data to an XLSX file is using [FrostedSheets](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/frostedsheets).

*Full disclaimer, I created FrostedSheets.*

The easiest approach is to use a nested `List` to model the rows and columns. Then, append the nested `List` to a worksheet. Finally, write the workbook to an `OutputStream`. Here's an example:

```
import com.emmanuelrosa.frostedsheets.*

def data = [
    ['first name', 'last name', 'age'],
    ['John', 'Doe', '30'],
    ['Jane', 'Smith', '25']
]

def workbook = FrostedWorkbook.createXLSX()

workbook['name of sheet'] << data

new FileOutputStream('somefile.xlsx').withStream { stream ->
    workbook.write(stream)
}
```